# Find the sum of the first $n$ positive integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

I just wanted to double-check my work on this problem. The problem states,

Let $a$ and $k$ be any positive integers. Find the sum $a+(a+1)+(a+2)+\cdots+(a+k)$.

Saying the summation is equal to ${n(n+1)\over 2}$, I got the answer ${(a+k)(a+k+1)\over 2}$, or ${a^2 \over 2}+ak+{a \over 2}+{k^2 \over2}+{k \over 2}$.

Does this make sense?

Comment: it is $$\frac{1}{2}(k+2ak+k^2)$$

Comment: If you know that $1+2+3+\cdots+k = \dfrac{k(k+1)} 2,$ then you can say $$ a + (a+1) + (a+2) + \cdots + (a+k) = (a+a+a+ \cdots + a) + (1+2+3+\cdots + k) = a(k+1) + \frac{k(k+1)} 2 = (k+1)\frac{a+k} 2. $$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I believe that you need another term $2a$ in your parentheses.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Do you mean $(k+1)\frac{2a+k}{2}$?

Comment: aha, do you thin k there is a mistake?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, yes, I think that Michael's argument gives the correct answer, which means that yours is missing a term $2a$ inside the parentheses.

Comment: hm it is $$ka+\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$$

Comment: @RideTheWavelet : Yes. $\qquad$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner The sum is $(a+0)+(a+1)+\cdots+(a+k),$ so we should have $(k+1)a.$

Comment: ok ist started with Zero my mistake

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is it that you want to compute? The sum $a+(a+1)+\dots+(a+k)$? Then your answer is not entirely correct. Take $$ \begin{aligned}a+(a+1)+\dots+(a+k) &= 1+2+\dots+(a+k) - (1+2+\dots+(a-1)) 
\\& = \frac{(a+k+1)(a+k)}{2} - \frac{(a-1)a}{2}. \end{aligned} $$

Answer (score 0):

We may rewrite your sum as $(k+1)a+\sum_{j=1}^{k}j,$ and then apply the formula for the sum of the first $k$ integers to get the result $$(k+1)a+\frac{k(k+1)}{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but no, your method does not make sense.

As undoubtedly many answers will show, you can use that formula, but not in the way you use it.

The $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ formula is for the sum of the $n$ numbers $1$ through $n$, so your $\frac{(a+k)(a+k+1)}{2}$ would be the sum of the numbers $1$ through $a+k$, rather than $a$ through $a+k$